# Не получается настроить локальную сеть между 2 Windows10 ПК

Tags: windows-10

В общем, есть 1 ноут, один ПК(оба windows10), оба подключены к wi-fi роутеру. Ноут по wi-fi, пк через кабель.
По началу не получалось соединить их вообще никак. В результате долгого гугления b некоторых действий пришел к тому, что могу открыть с ноута ПК через введение адреса вида: \PKname\ в проводник.(при этом в директории "Сеть" ничего не отображается). Зайдя по локалке в ПК я могу открыть папку "общие". Тем не менее, другие папки, к которым я разрешил общий доступ я открыть не могу.
В чём может быть дело?

Answer (score 0):

Тоже была такая проблема, только рабочих станций с 10-кой было больше, плюс Linux-овые машины. Помогли следующие шаги:

- Панель управления - Программы и компоненты - Включение и отключение компонентов Windows - находим и ставим галку на Поддержка общего доступа к файлам SMB 1.0/CIFS
- По этой ссылке [Не удается включить сетевое обнаружение в сети и Центр управления сетями в Windows Server 2008, Windows Server 2008 R2 или Windows Server 2012](https://support.microsoft.com/ru-ru/help/2722035/you-cannot-turn-on-network-discovery-in-network-and-sharing-center-in) проверил работу перечисленных служб на Windows 10, и включил что было отключено.

Теперь все работает как часы.

Можно еще проверить настройки доступа к локальным папкам для пользователя на вкладе "Безопасность" свойства папки и настройки доступа на вкладке "Доступ -> Расширенная настройка - Разрешения" в свойствах разделяемой папки.